# Argument No Specified for Parameter Public Overridable OVerloads Function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a search by like characters for a datagrid. My code was working but something happened and caused me to receive this error with my datagridadapter any idea what may have happened and how to fix? Error says TableAdapter is not a part of my form but it is

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Search_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1_Search.TextChanged
    Dim Search As String = "%" + TextBox1_Search.Text + "%"     ' Declare a Search String So We Can Search By Wildcard % Like    

    Me.VisitorlogTableAdapter.FillBySearchByNameAndSignOutNull(Me.DataSet21.Visitorlog, Search, Search)
End Sub
```

Comment: That error doesn't mean Tableadapter is not part of your form, it means you overloaded a sub "FillBySearchByNameAndSignOutNull" within your class, and are missing an argument that it's expecting

Comment: Thanks. I got it situated.